# Dynamically add content to an existing widget area

Tags: widgets, hooks, sidebar

I have an existing widget area / sidebar.  Rather than adding content to it via Appearance ? Widgets in the Dashboard, I want to inject content into the widget area from functions.php.

Is there hook that allows this?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes by using `widget_text` inject content into the widget area

Add the following code into your function.php file

```
function widget_content( $content )
{
    // add $content as you want
    return $content;
}

add_filter( 'widget_text', 'widget_content', 99 );
```

Comment: Great. Thank you, @amitrh.  How would I target a specific widget area?  I know the widget name.

Comment: Hey use [is_active_widget](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_active_widget) to target widget area by passing widget id

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can write a function in the functions.php file and call that function via the widget.

Functions.php:

```
function myFunction() {
    //do something here
} 
add_shortcode('wp_my_function', 'myFunction');

//Allow write shortcode in widgets  
add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');
```

In the Widget:

Use the text widget, write in the shortcode: `[wp_my_function]`